# Conversion Upload : how to set conversion window on each conversion upload?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm trying to upload conversions using OfflineConversionFeed. I wanted to set conversion window =90 days for each conversion. I believe this can be set by using ctcLookbackWindow however that function is not listed in the document - https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/OfflineConversionFeedService.OfflineConversionFeed

Has anyone tried this before? Is it possible to set conversion window on each conversion upload?

```
    $feed = new OfflineConversionFeed();
    $feed->setconversionName($conversionName);
    $feed->setconversionTime($conversionTime);
    $feed->setconversionValue($conversionValue);
    $feed->setgoogleClickId($gClId);

    $offlineConversionOperation = new OfflineConversionFeedOperation();
    $offlineConversionOperation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
    $offlineConversionOperation->setOperand($feed);
    $offlineConversionOperations = array($offlineConversionOperation);
    $result = $offlineConversionService->mutate($offlineConversionOperations);
    $feed = $result->value[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ctcLookBackWindow](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/ConversionTrackerService.ConversionTracker#ctclookbackwindow) can only be modified using the [ConversionTrackerService](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201809/ConversionTrackerService). Also, please note that this is only editable for AdWords Conversions and Upload Conversions.

Comment: Thanks Githin! I actually had modified the ctcLookBackWindow while creating conversion action (which I believe is a one time action) however I want to set conversion window every time I fire a conversion through GCLID. 
The issue is that whenever I fire a conversion through API, the conversion window is getting set to 1 day instead of 90 days. Due to this the conversions on our DB doesnt match with Google ads. So as a solution I want to send conversion window = 90 days on every pixel fires. Is it possible ? Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks